# Ajax changes drop down menu doesn't remain the same

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a small issue on a search form. PLease check this:http://www.fortisfitness.ca/test/script.php

What's the problem? When I select the country, the "cities" drop down refreshes with the specific values for that country. All good, but when I select a city, the data is loaded corectly from the database, but the city value from the dropdown menu remains at "All" value.

I use two ajax functions. One for loading data into the table and one for refreshing the dropdown list. Please help . . . Thank you!

Comment: It seems the problem is that you reload city options every time the city changes.

Comment: Sir, I've aded an alert into the ajax function wich refreshes the city list and it didn't triggered. I think it's about the SELECT attribute after the list reloads . . .

Comment: I haven't looked into your code much, but Firebug shows that city options are reloaded after every time you select the particular city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not about your JavaScript code, its somewhere on the server site.

the request of the ajax call, when selecting a city, is like this:

```
get_city.php?S_City=&D_Country=&D_City=%20Sao%20Miguel%A0&S_Site=&priceh=&time=&pag=1
```

the response is:

```
<option SELECTED value="">All</option><option value=""></option><option value=" Äkkilähtö"> Äkkilähtö</option>
...
```

in your ajax complete function you set the html code of the dropdown with the response:

```
$("#titles1").html(msg);
```

as you can see, the response returns the dropdown box with the "all" option selected. so, take a closer look at your php code!

Comment: I don't think this ajax call should be called at all.

Comment: Is the same way for the country list. This sets ALL to be selected. It works for country. Why shouldn't work here? The problem is at ajax cal. I have two calls on that script. And this second it seems it is called every time the main function is caled :(

Comment: Just removed it. The result is the same